# New terminals close instantly in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot open any new terminals on my VS Code 1.82.2 on Windows 10. Every time I click "New terminal", it'll quickly show the following error message before closing:

```
-noexit : The term '-noexit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -noexit -command try { . c:\Users\FINDarkside\AppData\Local\Programs\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-noexit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried reinstalling VS Code, disabling all plugins, clearing all custom settings and deleting `Code/User` folder completely but none of these helped. Any ideas?

Comment: for what terminal profiles does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to get powershell working again. All I had to do was to disable `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled`. It caused all default terminal profile to crash even `pwsh` which it is supposed to support.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Custom Init": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": [
         "-file",
         "${env:APPDATA}\\PowerShell\\custom-init.ps1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Custom Init"
}
```

Try setting this above code as your Terminal profile.

Comment: Also, set "path" to cmd.exe if you want the Terminal to be the command prompt.

Comment: Hmm, cmd.exe in path fixes the issue, but then I can't use powershell. pwsh.exe in the config will cause the same error as in my question.

Comment: I wonder why, sorry.

Comment: Well either way I'll accept this answer because at least I can now use terminal in VScode again. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome:), I still am wondering why you cant use powershell, because I removed the arg that was causing the problem. I would try debugging, but I'm not a web dev, so thats off the table.